# Upgrade to CKS 3.0 - Metaweblog.ashx won't work

Tags: blog

We're using windows live writer for our blog and therefore we're using the metaweblog.ashx. But after the upgrade from CKS 2.0 to CKS 3.0 there is an error when calling metaweblog.ashx.

The error is:

> An error occurred during the
>   compilation of the requested file, or
>   one of its dependencies. The type or
>   namespace name 'Components' does not
>   exist in the namespace
>   'CommunityServer' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

What should I do to get the handler up and running so that we can use windows live writer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem is solved. In the newest verstion oh Windows Live Writer 2011 you don't need the metaweblog.ashx. Just do the following to connect to your blog.
Add Blog -> Other Services -> Enter normal webadress without path to metaweblog.ashx and credentials (WLW knows what service to use).